# python queue jumps to next item before current is completed

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm using a queue to receive a task from another thread and get it done one by one. thread module puts item in queue based on file creation event on the disk and the main thread is supposed to process the files one by one as they get added to queue on First In First Out basis. Processing one task/file may take a few seconds to a minute.

The issue I'm facing is, as opposed to processing queue items one by one using queue.get() in synchronous way, some time, more than one concurrent processes starts in asynchronous manner. Here is the code looks like:

```
#code in main thread
q = Queue.Queue(0)
while True:
    qItem = q.get()
    do_something_with(qItem)  # this may take few seconds to minutes

#code in other thread
items = ['one', 'two', 'three']
for item in items:
    q.put(item)
```

The above code it supposed to process item "one" then "two" and then "three". What happens in my actual program, the do_something_with method starts processing item "two" before processing of item "one" finished.

Comment: could you add more code than this? threading is no easy thing, and perhaps the problem lies somewhere else...?

Comment: what could be wrong is the timing, the thread adding the queue may be finishing slower than the thread that is doing stuff to the item in the queues. So perhaps if you delay the start of the "doing" thread then that should help.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, you create more threads than you *think*!

Are you guarding the main block with `if __name__=='__main__':`?

Otherwise you might simply be creating more threads than you realise, and they might be consuming the items in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

you are appending a list to `l`. This is what is causing the error.

`l.append(outl[a:b])` makes a slice of the list `outl` and adds that list to `l`

use `l.extend(outl[a:b])`